# How to find a child item inside Pivot and make it visible false

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uno-platform

I have a Pivot with child as Grid. I am trying to find that grid on pivot selection change. My code is like this

```
  <Pivot x:Name="mainContentPivot"  SelectionChanged="mainContentPivot_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.headerElement, Mode=OneWay}" >

        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:HeaderUIModel">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Name="grd">

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>


   private void mainContentPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PivotItem item = (sender as Pivot).ContainerFromItem((sender as Pivot).SelectedItem) as PivotItem;
        var gridView = FindElementInVisualTree<GridView>(item);
    }

    private T FindElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
        if (count == 0) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                var result = FindElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

On selected item change I am getting gridView  as NULL always. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Xaml you have a `Grid` whereas in your C# code-behind you have a `GridView`, is that the problem? Those are completely different controls despite the similar name.